# Selenium webdriver for magento

Tags: magento-1.9, testing

Can anybody provide a link for a guide on using selenium webDriver for magento , Like the one below, which is for using Selenium firefox IDE.

http://aionhill.com/setup-selenium-automatic-tests-for-magento

Or brief on the steps included for accomplishing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Selenium webdriver with webdriver.io,nodejs and Mocha framework to test the Magento sites for the past few years. You can get an insight about the automation implementation with the below details.

Reference links:

http://webdriver.io

http://www.dckap.com/blog/auomation-testing-node-js-webdriver-io-mocha/